# Why does my unit test fail when the results look "correct" to me?

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn python.  I started with this unit test:

```
import unittest

from rna_transcription import to_rna

class RNATranscriptionTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_transcribes_cytosine_to_guanine(self):
        self.assertEqual(to_rna('C'), 'G')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I wrote my method as such:

```
def to_rna(dna_strand):
    rna_strand = []

    for x in dna_strand:
        print('looking at:', x)
        if x == 'C':
            rna_strand.append('G')


    return rna_strand
```

When I run the unit test, it fails with this error:

```
AssertionError: ['G'] != 'G'
```

I'm not sure what is wrong here. I don't get the output. G looks like G to me other than its written differently.  What did I do wrong?

Comment: Left: `['G']` is a list with one element: the string `'G'`. Right: This is just the string `'G'`

Comment: Look again Matt `['G'] != 'G'`

Comment: I recommend Biopyton for this stuff btw https://github.com/biopython/biopython

Comment: The left side from the assertion is a one-element Python `list` while the right side is a string (`str` in Python). A list cannot be equal to a string. `... == ['C']` should work. Your method returns a list by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`['G']` is not the same as `'G'`. The former is a `list`, the later a `str`. A list can never be equal to a string.

But your test is correct in the sense that it points out that the behaviour of your function is not the expected one. If you want it to return a string, you would need it to look like this.

```
def to_rna(dna_strand):
    rna_strand = ''

    for x in dna_strand:
        print('looking at:', x)
        # if I recall my biology class correctly 
        rna_strand += 'G' if x == 'C' else x

    return rna_strand
```

Note that there are more efficient ways to do this, but I did not update your code too much for the sake of the example. You could actually do that.

```
def to_rna(dna_strand):
    return dna_strand.replace('C', 'G')
```

Comment: never say never... `class list(list): def __eq__(self, _): return True` ... `list('G') == 'G'` > `True`

Comment: Well, technically, this is not `__builtin__.list` anymore, so still correct. Even though there are actual hacks you can do to really change the builtin class

Comment: thank you.  that is clear example of what I got wrong.